# It is posible to write hs_err_pid*.log in a specific directory (different than the class directory) when java virtual machine crash?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-crash

When a java application crash outside the java virtual machine generate a log file hs_err_pidXXXX.log in the same directory than the class running.

It's posible generate this file in a different directory?

My client want to change to read only this directory, but i don't like to lose this files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the -XX:ErrorFile JVM arg will work.

See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5107646 and https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=5515dc81f6e66149b8cd377f59bf1?bug_id=4872551 for details

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html contains a list of VM options (Thanks @Peter Štibraný who's earlier answer added this link)

Comment: Yes, this is right one. Check also list of all config options: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html