# when hs_err_pidxxxx.log will generate?

Tags: java

```
public class Crash {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

How to crash the JVM so it will generate the hs_err_pidxxxx.log

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200/how-do-you-crash-a-jvm?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The log file is located in the "current directory" of the process by default. This can changed - see [It is posible to write hs_err_pid*.log in a specific directory (different than the class directory) when java virtual machine crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195114/it-is-posible-to-write-hs-err-pid-log-in-a-specific-directory-different-than-t).

Comment: I am not getting the hs_err_pidxxxx.log???can you suggest me piece of code so it will generate the log ???

Comment: See the link in question comment for advice on how to force a JVM crash.

Comment: but the  hs_err_pidxxxx.log file is not generating?? why